# AWS AMI Virtual Host showing

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, centos, httpd.conf, vhosts

i have tried creating the virtual hosts via this following link

[Digital Ocean Virtual Host](http://digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7)

However it is using only first vhost settings. i have tried many tutorials but nothing is working.
Finally i have put the vhost settings in httpd.conf file

```
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  abc.edu
        ServerAlias www.abc.edu
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc/frontend/dist
        <Directory /var/www/html/abc/frontend/dist>
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerName  apiabc.edu
        ServerAlias www.apiabc.edu
        Alias /static /var/www/html/abc/abc/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/abc/abc/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/abc/abc/abc>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess abc python-path=/var/www/html/abc/abc python-home=/var/www/html/abc/env
        WSGIProcessGroup abc
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/abc/abc/abc/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why `:8000` instead of `:80`?

Comment: Actually I have two domains . One is for frontend and one is for backend. I tried with same port i.e 80 but it wasn't working. So I tried this way